# Expression that filters out any string that's not 12 characters in MS Report Builder 3.0

Tags: filter, reportbuilder3.0

I have folks entering data incorrectly. Either too many, or too few numbers in a string field. I need an expression for MS Report Builder that returns anything that's NOT 12 characters. I can change the field type if it would make for an easier expression.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Am brand new at this, so I've just been grasping at straws.  I can't find an example expression that does anything like this online, so I don't have anywhere to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Filters option within DataSet Properties on the Dataset.  Add a new filter.  For the expression, click on the ***fx*** button and enter:

=LEN(Fields!Field_Name.Value)

Change the type to Integer.

Change the Operator to <>.

Set the Value to 12.

Click OK and you should be good to go.

[image]